# DateTimeParseException: Text '2 11, 11 2021 21:35' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, timestamp, datetimeformatter

Am trying to get `Date` from `DatePicker` and `Time` from `TimePicker` and parse the values from these two classes into a single Java Timestamp with `DateTimeFormatter` but logcat throws this `exception`

```
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 
     Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2 11, 11 2021 21:35' could not be parsed at index 0
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:238)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:341)
```

And the code am trying to format the date with is this one

```java
         dpicker=datView.findViewById(R.id.user_date);
         year=dpicker.getYear();
         month=dpicker.getMonth();
         day=dpicker.getDayOfMonth();
         int hour=timepicker.getCurrentHour();
         int min=timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
         String pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm";
         String timestamp= (String.valueOf(month)+" "+String.valueOf(day)+", "+String.valueOf(day)
                 +" "+String.valueOf(year)+" "+String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(min));
         DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
         LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(timestamp));
         mytimestamp=Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime.toString());
```

Comment: post it as an answer please

Answer (score 1):

1. using `day` two times:

```
String timestamp= (String.valueOf(month)+" "+
                   String.valueOf(day)+", "+   
                   // String.valueOf(day)+" "+    // REPEATED, delete!
                   String.valueOf(year)+" "+
                   String.valueOf(hour)+":"+
                   String.valueOf(min));
```

---

2. use single letters for **parsing**

```
String pattern = "M d, y H:m";
```

<sup>also note that 3 letters means text rules (as opposed to number rules for less than 3 letters)</sup>

---

3. use `LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute)`, ignore previous 2 points:

```
int year = ...  // actual code
int month =     // "
int day = ...   // "
int hour = ...  // "
int min = ...   // " 
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, min);
```

3 a) If your date picker numbers the months of the year from 0 through 11 (a terrible habit that some date pickers have), you need to add 1 to the month number since `LocalDateTime` sanely expects months to be numbered 1 through 12.

---

4. do not transform to string to obtain `Timestamp` (assuming `java.sql.Timestamp`):

```
mytimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);  // no toString here
```